# Merging two matrices with different sizes

Tags: r, matrix, merge

I have two matrices like

I want to get some intersection

```
 > head(small[1:3,])
  Chrom1    Start1      End1 Strand1 Chrom2    Start2      End2
1      1  28677074  28677079       +      1  28706324  28706329
2      1 186383731 186383738       +      1 186383731 186383732
3      1 245902589 245902590       +      1 246007384 246007385
  Strand2
1       -
2       -
3       -
> 
    > dim(small)
[1] 1594    8
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mkplrg1236f8qtd/111.txt?dl=0

And a big matrix

```
> head(big[1:3,])
  Ensembl_Gene_ID Chromosome_Name Gene_Start Gene_End
1 ENSG00000233440              13   23708313 23708703
2 ENSG00000207157              13   23726725 23726825
3 ENSG00000229483              13   23743974 23744736
  Associated_Gene_Name X5UTR_Start X5UTR_End X3UTR_Start X3UTR_End
1              HMGA1P6          NA        NA          NA        NA
2               RNY3P4          NA        NA          NA        NA
3            LINC00362          NA        NA          NA        NA
  Transcript_count Gene_Biotype Exon_Chr_Start Exon_Chr_End
1                1   pseudogene       23708313     23708703
2                1     misc_RNA       23726725     23726825
3                1      lincRNA       23744691     23744736
  Exon_Rank_in_Transcript Ensembl_Transcript_ID Transcript_Start
1                       1       ENST00000418454         23708313
2                       1       ENST00000384428         23726725
3                       1       ENST00000414345         23743974
  Transcript_End strand
1       23708703      1
2       23726825     -1
3       23744736     -1
> dim(big)
[1] 1048575      18
>
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bit4iw2ne19td63/big.txt?dl=0

I need somethis like

```
Chrom1  Start1  End1    Strand1 Chrom2  Start2  End2    Strand2 GeneName.node1  GeneName.node2
chr1    14480603    14481217    +   chr1    14747789    14748719    -   -   -
chr1    16169956    16170596    +   chr1    16217823    16218463    -   RP11-169K16.9   SPEN
```

I have R script like

```
#### Determining breakpoint locations: and adding to table

small$breakpoint1 <- apply(small[,c("Strand1","Start1","End1")], 1,
                             function(x) ifelse(x[1] == "+",as.numeric(x[3]),
                                                as.numeric(x[2])))
small$breakpoint2 <- apply(small[,c("Strand2","Start2","End2")], 1,
                             function(x) ifelse(x[1] == "+",as.numeric(x[3]),
                                                as.numeric(x[2])))
svinfo$breakpoint1.ordered <- apply(svinfo[,c("breakpoint1","breakpoint2")],1,
                                     function(x) min(as.numeric(x[1]),as.numeric(x[2])))
svinfo$breakpoint2.ordered <- apply(svinfo[,c("breakpoint1","breakpoint2")],1,
                                     function(x) max(as.numeric(x[1]),as.numeric(x[2])))

  #######
  ### Start SV annotation:
  gr.hg19.gene <-  GRanges(
    seqnames = Rle(hg19$Chromosome_Name),
    ranges = IRanges(start=as.numeric(hg19$Gene_Start), end = as.numeric(hg19$Gene_End)),
    EnsemblGeneID = hg19$Ensembl_Gene_ID,
    GeneName = hg19$Associated_Gene_Name,
    TranscriptCount = hg19$Transcript_count,
    ExonChrStart = hg19$Exon_Chr_Start,
    ExonChrEnd = hg19$Exon_Chr_End,
    ExonRankInTranscript = hg19$Exon_Rank_in_Transcript,
    EnsemblTranscriptID = hg19$Ensembl_Transcript_ID,
    TranscriptStart = hg19$Transcript_Start,
    TranscriptEnd = hg19$Transcript_End,
    GeneStrand = hg19$Strand,
    ExonID = paste(hg19$Exon_Chr_Start,hg19$Exon_Chr_End,sep=".")
  )

  gr.svinfo.node1 <- GRanges(
    seqnames = Rle(svinfo$Chrom1),
    ranges = IRanges(start=as.numeric(svinfo$breakpoint1), end = as.numeric(svinfo$breakpoint1)),
    Type = svinfo$Type,
    Node1.Strand = svinfo$Strand1,
    ID = svinfo$ID
  )
  gr.svinfo.node2 <- GRanges(
    seqnames = Rle(svinfo$Chrom2),
    ranges = IRanges(start=as.numeric(svinfo$breakpoint2), end = as.numeric(svinfo$breakpoint2)),
    Type = svinfo$Type,
    Node2.Strand = svinfo$Strand2,
    ID = svinfo$ID
  )
```

But I don't know how to get genes related to each parts of small matrix

Could any one please help me?

Comment: I think you want something like `dplyr::left_join`

Comment: Try: `merged=merge(small,big,x.by="chromStart",y.by="chromEnd", all.x=T, all.y=F)`

Comment: Thank you but all returned NA for Gene

Comment: A reproducible example would make it easier to get the answer. Your providing the ```head``` but it doesn't be appear that there's an actual overlap there.

Answer (score 2):

The following should do it as a first step.  First load your (modified) data example:

```
small <- read.table(text = "Chromosome chromStart  chromEnd
1          1   28677074  28677079
2          1  186383731 186383738
3          1  245902589 245902590
4          2   56345643  56345645
5          3   59766214  59766217
6          3   60270545  60270548")

big <- read.table(text = "
Chromosome chromStart chromEnd      Gene
1         1   28677075 28677078   HMGA1P6
2         13   23726725 23726825    RNY3P4
3         13   23743974 23744736 LINC00362
4         13   23743974 23744736 LINC00362
5         13   23791571 23791673  RNU6-58P
6         13   23817659 23821323  TATDN2P3")
```

Next, the code for identifying te genes corresponding to the regions.

```
small$Gene <- NA  # Initialize an "empty" colum to fill
for (i in seq_len(nrow(small))) {
  # Find indicies where the genes falls into the chromosome and region
  j <- which(big$Chromosome == small[i, "Chromosome"] &
               big$chromStart >= small[i, "chromStart"] &
               big$chromEnd <= small[i, "chromEnd"])

  # Fetch the gene corresponding to the indicies and collapse (if more than one)
  small[i, "Gene"] <- paste(big$Gene[j], collapse = ";")
}

print(small)
#  Chromosome chromStart  chromEnd    Gene
#1          1   28677074  28677079 HMGA1P6
#2          1  186383731 186383738        
#3          1  245902589 245902590        
#4          2   56345643  56345645        
#5          3   59766214  59766217        
#6          3   60270545  60270548
```

Of course, using a for-loop might not be optimal. But notice we a looping over the `small` matrix, and utilizing vectorization by comparing each row in `small` with all rows in `big`. It should be fairly quick even on your full data.

As you need to compare each gene with every region *on the chromosome*, you can probably optimize code a bit more for speed.

I have "accounted" for the possibility a more than one gene might fall in the region defined by the records of `small`.

**Edit:**

If you are looking for simply "overlap" of chromosome regions and genes, you need to define `j` above like the following instead:

```
j <- which(
  big$Chromosome == small[i, "Chromosome"] & (
    (small[i, "chromStart"] <= big$chromStart & big$chromStart <= small[i, "chromEnc"]) | # Gene starts in region
    (small[i, "chromStart"] <= big$chromEnd & big$chromEnd <= small[i, "chromEnd"])  # Gene ends in region
  ) 
)
```

If I am not mistaken. Basically, this should check if the genes start *or* stop within the region.

Comment: Thank you but returned empty column Gene in small matrix :(

Comment: Do you agree with the logic of the code? I.e. for a given region in `small`, you want find the genes that fall within it, correct?

Comment: Yes you right, so you mean there is no genes in overlap of ranges in two matrices?

Comment: The code above looks for genes whose regions are *entirely* contained with in the regions defined in small. It does *not* check for **general** overlap. The start of the gene should be *after* the start of the chromosome region, and the end of the gene should be *before* the end of the chromosome region. (If I have not made a mistake). Do you have any examples of 'overlap'?

Comment: I have added some code which tries to look for "overlap". If neither works (depending on what you want), I suspect there are no examples in your data.

Comment: Sorry I have small matrix and big matrix (annotation) even R code for annotation but I don't know how to use that

Answer (score 1):

This seems like `foverlaps` from data.table would be useful. See this answer:

[Finding Overlaps between interval sets / Efficient Overlap Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815032/finding-overlaps-between-interval-sets-efficient-overlap-joins)

Using @Anders Ellern Bilgrau's dataset, this implements `foverlaps`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(small)
setDT(big)

setkey(big, Chromosome, chromStart, chromEnd)

foverlaps(small, big)

#   Chromosome chromStart chromEnd    Gene i.chromStart i.chromEnd
#1:          1   28677075 28677078 HMGA1P6     28677074   28677079
#2:          1         NA       NA    <NA>    186383731  186383738
#3:          1         NA       NA    <NA>    245902589  245902590
#4:          2         NA       NA    <NA>     56345643   56345645
#5:          3         NA       NA    <NA>     59766214   59766217
#6:          3         NA       NA    <NA>     60270545   60270548
```

Comment: Thank you what that returned I don't know how relate with my samples